# Jagged Edges with Eevee Render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Im very new to Blender and was following a tutorial online to create metallic like shapes/type. Every time I render I get the following quality of really jagged or pixelated edges within the shape. Even within render mode it looks jagged and low quality.

After looking at various threads on this forum, upping the sampling and resolution % I cannot seem to find a way to solve this issue.

Can anyone help or advise on ways around this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Probably topology.  Good subsurf topology is: all quad; no 6+ poles; 3 and 5 poles placed on most planar parts of mesh; planar, square faces.  Can't say whether your meshes meet those criteria without a wireframe.  Online tutorials are often of limited value.

Comment: can you provide a blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: @Chris Yeah of course here it is https://we.tl/t-uJihg5tz42